# Creating GUI with PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qt-designer, qtreewidgetitem

I have some Python command line tools ready. So now I am trying to create a GUI so that with one click, I can execute the tool. I am trying out Pyside and creating a QTreewidget at the moment. I am inputting the items one by one on QT designer. However, when i use pyside-uic to convert it into a .py file, the Qtree items are numbered item1, item2 etc. for example,

```
 self.treeWidget_1.setObjectName("treeWidget_1")
 item_0 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget_1)
 item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
 item_2 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_1)
```

And i couldn't find anywhere to edit the properties (by giving each item a tag/name to identify it with) from the QT designer. Can anyone help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this in Designer. You will need to add the items in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need item_i. If you want to do something with your object, you have to inherit in a class the class generated by pysyde-ui(pyuic4). Next you can use `self.treewidget_1` in your class with for example `self.treewidget_1.topLevelItem(i)`